# SerializationException from System.Web.UI.Page.SaveAllState() on a member marked with NonSerializedAttribute

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, serialization

I get a serialization error on a page containing a custom control. the control has a member (`dataContext`) of a type (`EntityContext`) that is non-serializable, and marked as such.

this is the error:

> Type 'Entities.EntityContext' in
>   Assembly '...' is not marked as
>   serializable.
>
> [SerializationException: Type
>   '...Entities.EntityContext'
>   in Assembly '...' is
>   not marked as serializable.]
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.InternalGetSerializableMembers(RuntimeType
>   type) +7733643
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(Type
>   type, StreamingContext context) +258
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitMemberInfo()
>   +111    System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object
>   obj, ISurrogateSelector
>   surrogateSelector, StreamingContext
>   context, SerObjectInfoInit
>   serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter
>   converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter)
>   +161    System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.Serialize(Object
>   obj, ISurrogateSelector
>   surrogateSelector, StreamingContext
>   context, SerObjectInfoInit
>   serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter
>   converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter)
>   +51    System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object
>   graph, Header[] inHeaders,
>   __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck) +410
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream
>   serializationStream, Object graph,
>   Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck) +134
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream
>   serializationStream, Object graph) +13
>   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.SerializeValue(SerializerBinaryWriter
>   writer, Object value) +4966
>
> [ArgumentException: Error serializing
>   value
>   '...Entities.EntityContext'
>   of type
>   '...Entities.EntityContext.']
>   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.SerializeValue(SerializerBinaryWriter
>   writer, Object value) +5425
>   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Serialize(Stream
>   outputStream, Object stateGraph) +163 
>   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Serialize(Object
>   stateGraph) +99
>   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.System.Web.UI.IStateFormatter.Serialize(Object
>   state) +37
>   System.Web.UI.Util.SerializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter
>   formatter, Object stateGraph) +55
>   System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Save()
>   +143    System.Web.UI.Page.SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium(Object
>   state) +190
>   System.Web.UI.Page.SaveAllState()
>   +1466    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5477

This is the control:

```
public class EntityDataSource : ObjectDataSource
{
    [NonSerialized] private EntityContext dataContext;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the data context. (This is used by the page at runtime.)
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The data context.</value>
    // ReSharper disable MemberCanBePrivate.Global
    public EntityContext DataContext
    // ReSharper restore MemberCanBePrivate.Global
    {
        get { return dataContext; }
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        dataContext = new EntityContext(SessionProvider.GetContext());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Viewstate is not implemented. This value allways return <c>false</c>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="NotSupportedException">Exception is thrown when setting this value.</exception>
    [Browsable(false)]
    public override bool EnableViewState
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
        set
        {
            //Throws exception if value is true.
            if (value)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("Viewstate is not enabled on this control.");
            }
        }
    }

    public override void Dispose()
    {
        if (DataContext != null)
        {
            DataContext.Dispose();
        }

        base.Dispose();
    }
}
```

It almost seems like the page doesn't honor the `NonSerializedAttribute`. 
I have omitted the company and product names from the namespaces.

Comment: I guess i should have stated a more precise question, as most people misunderstood my problem. Still, thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding the problem ...

I take it the instance is beeing serialized and you wish it not to be so. Well, if you cannot change the way the instance is handled, change the way it serializes. Implement System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable and just set the initial state in the deserialization constructor (required when implementing the interface). This way at least you circumvent the exception (be sure this still results in correct behaviour) and you add nothing much to the stream (other than type information). As you need no state persisted, you simply do not add items to the dictionary.

Comment: This was the workaround I ended up with. Still, it almost seems like a bug, though.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you add the `SerializableAttribute` to the `EntityDataSource` class:

```
[Serializable]
public class EntityDataSource : ObjectDataSource
{
    [NonSerialized] private EntityContext dataContext;
    // etc...
}
```

The `[NonSerialized]` attribute is ignored if the class is not marked as `[Serializable]`.

Whether the system can actually serialize the class you're wanting it to is another matter.

Comment: Well, this class isn't really serializable, so it wouldn't solve my problem.

Comment: The control inheriting ObjectDataSource is declared in the page markup, and thus is serialized by the page when saving view state. I have no need for serialization at all.

Comment: The NonSerialized attribute is ignored if the class is not marked as [Serializable]. Whether you can actually serialize your class or not depends on your situation. I'm answering your question of why you're seeing what you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to put the [NonSerialized] attribute on the property as well?
Also, if any of the types you use in your class (and that you may have omitted in the example) inherits from EntityContext you are in trouble.

Comment: [NonSerialized] may only decorate fields. Nothing inherits from EntityContext.

Comment: OK, but then I think the problem is not that the [NonSerialized] Attribute is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything else that you aren't showing on the control? In particular; you inherit from `ObjectDataSource` - I assume you give it the data-context (or some related object) at some point?

I would personally have no expectation that `ObjectDataSource` should serialize. It isn't `ISerializable` nor `[Serializable]`, for starters. Additionally it has lots of events... and events are rarely the friend of serialization (when using `BinaryFormatter`, at least).

Ultimately, you should serialize **state**; but `ObjectDataSource` isn't state - it is (more-or-less) part of the UI implementation. Just attempting to serialize a *vanilla* `ObjectDataSource` is enough to cause an exception.

In short; I don't think that you should be including this control in the scope of `SaveAllState`, perhaps marking **the field to your control** as `[NonSerialized]`.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure I fully understand... your trying to serialise a class that is not serialisable, and are wondering why the NonSerialised attribute is not being applied?

Is there something I am missing?